# Python universal scraper for all postcodes on a page hidden inside javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-requests

I'm currently trying to create a universal web scraper which will pick up on all postcodes on a page but I'm finding it really difficult if a page hides their office locations within some javascript.

My scraper:

```py
def parse(url):

    try:
        print(url)
        postcode_regex_pattern = r"([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})"
        compiled_pattern = re.compile(postcode_regex_pattern)
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
            }
        page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        # print(page.status_code)
        if page.status_code == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
            info_to_store = {
                            'url': url,
                            'postcodes': [],
                            }
            visible_text_in_page = text_from_html(soup)
            matches = re.findall(compiled_pattern, visible_text_in_page)
            pcs = [match[1] for match in matches]
            if len(pcs) > 0:
                info_to_store['postcodes'] = list(set(pcs))
    except Exception as e:
        print('{url}: ' + str(e))
        pass
```

Two good examples that my scraper does not work on:

https://home.kpmg/uk/en/home/about/offices.html

https://www.twilio.com/company

Does anyone have any advice? I do not want to use selenium.

Comment: I reckon I'm going to have to use a headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [requests_html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) to render the page and then parse it with BeautifulSoup.
Python 3.6 and above is required.

Sample request

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('https://home.kpmg/uk/en/home/about/offices.html')
```